# Regular expression for css file with resourcequery

Tags: javascript, regex

what would be the regex to include files like

```
'../../cloud.css?raw'
```

I have `^.+\\.(css|sass|css?raw)$`but seems it is not correct for above path. whatwould be the regex toincludes file with .css?raw extenssion ??

Comment: You could escape the `\?` and match css with an optional `?raw` part `^.+\.(?:sass|css(?:\?raw)?)$` https://regex101.com/r/ZixyL9/1

Answer (score 0):

This is better, you need to escape `?` and you had a double `\\`: `^.+\.(css|sass|css\?raw)$`

A really good tool to try: https://regex101.com/

Example https://regex101.com/r/a2tAg7/1

Also if you don't need to capture, you can use a non-capturing group, this is even better: `^.+\.(?:css|sass|css\?raw)$` and finally `.+` is not needed as you have the end of match character here `$`.

You might also want to match `?raw` on sass as well?

So imo, best would be `\.(?:css|sass)(\?raw)?$`
Here is another example: https://regex101.com/r/V194mv/1

---

Comment: `\.(?:css|sass)(\?raw)?$` will also match `.sass?raw` which is not what is desired as described in the question

Comment: It is not described it does not want to match it, but anyway I offer both ways, 2 regexes.